Linux just won't start on my Inspiron 5521 due to kworker or systemd
I had a Thinkpad. It broke. I used this Inspiron 5521 laptop. It ran Windows fine, but as soon as I wanted to run Linux it would usually be stuck at kworker errors like kworker exited with a preempt count 1, but today I left it overnight and in the morning there were systemd messages as shown in the  below image.
The image contains a message that says Failed to start systemd-journald.service, and then on the other line it says file tmpfiles service-d/journald running (6h 30 min, / no limit)

Its not an SSD issue as I tried with other valid SSDs that do work.
System specs:
   Model: Dell Inspiron 5521
   RAM: 8GB
   SSD: Kingston SATA SSD 480GB
   Extra SSD not plugged in: Adata 128GB SATA SSD
   CPU: Core i7 3 gen
   GPU: Radeon 8730m
   IGPU: Intel HD graphics 4000

You've provided little for us to provide specific help with; we don't know what Ubuntu product, nor release of that unstated product you actually installed. Did you install Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? etc, what release of that product? How was it installed? Did it ever run? Did the live system run as expected pre-install? If you stop boot (installed system)  at runlevel 1 and login there?  OR what exactly did you try and importantly what are you using & asking about?

I tried to install ubuntu desktop i believe it was 24 lts and everytime i try installing this occurs

Ubuntu's Desktop system is a year.month release; as the year format (24) is used for snap only products; eg. Ubuntu Core 24 being the snap only version of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server. Ubuntu has ISOs using 3 installers for 24.04 LTS alone, so please be precise/clear with details if you prefer help; 24 itself will be only part of the detail & wasn't a desktop system; Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop was (ie 2024-April release of Desktop).
